# Big o notation and dominate term

Tags: big-o

I have a problem in determining the big O-notation and dominate term for fractions and logs.

What is the dominate term and big O for `100n / ( 2n + 1 )`?

What is the difference between `log( log( n ) )` and `log( n )` and which one is faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each polynomial in the equation you are trying to find the order of, scrap all but the highest order term.

For your example: `100n / (2n + 1)` would become `100n / 2n`. Which can then be reduced to `50` which is a constant, making it order `1`.

When looking at `log` equations we care about the fact that log is both monotonically increasing and less than linear in order. `log` being monotonically increasing means that log will always be increasing. `log` being of a lesser order than linear means that when combined as `log(log(n))` it will be grow even slower.

[Graph of `ln(x)` vs. `ln(ln(x))`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Mkrp.png)

As an example of a monotonic function that is greater than linear in order, you can look at `e^x`. Which gets even faster when you combined it with itself.

[Graph of `e^x` vs. `e^(e^x)`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwwAN.png)